# error magic zoom with javascript and html,css

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

My code contains five images, four of which are thumbnails,Are displayed by clicking  in the main img tag 
The problem is, besides changing the photo I want to zoom in  but Whenever the photo changes,show zoom for the same photo 
my code show result zoom just for fist img and i think it is related to js code this line  buti am not sure and i cannot solve it

result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";

**img in state of1**

[image]

**result zoom div not changing**

[image]

```js
<script>
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>

<script>
// Initiate zoom effect:
imageZoom("expandedImg", "myresult");
</script>
<script>
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");

  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    /* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    /* Style the images inside the grid */
    .column img {
      opacity: 0.8; 
      cursor: pointer; 
    }
    
    .column img:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    /* The expanding image container */
    .container {
      position: relative;
      display: none;
    }
    
    /* Expanding image text */
    #imgtext {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 15px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Closable button inside the expanded image */
    .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 15px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-zoom-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
<script>
```

```html
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="expandedImg" src="imgs/img4.jpg" width="300" height="240">
  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img   id="expandedImg"  src="imgs/img5.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imgs/img4.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imgs/img3.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imgs/img2.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve it after 5 min insert my question :))))
i should use this code

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");

  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
imageZoom("expandedImg", "myresult");
}
```